# How can I create an audio stop button? 

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, sdk, avaudioplayer

Basically the audio button works fine but the stop button doesn't. It gives me some issues but doesn't crash and does not work.

.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *elSonido4;

    -(IBAction)fajitas1:(id)sender;

    -(IBAction)stopPressed:(id)sender;
```

.m file:

```
@synthesize elSonido4;

-(IBAction)fajitas1:(id)sender{

    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"fajitas" ofType:@"m4a"];
    elSonido4=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]error:NULL];
    elSonido4.delegate=self;
    [elSonido4 play];

}


   - (IBAction)stopPressed:(id)sender{
    [elSonido4 pause];
}
```

Any suggestions? And if possible can I stop all sounds when changing views?

Comment: You are playing song using elSonido4 variable and stopping using audio1. Isn't it the main reason of error ?????

Comment: oops true.. but now that i changed it i get issues:  local declaration of 'elSonido4' hides instance variable

Answer (score 0):

remove `AVAudioPlayer*elSonido4;` line from your `-(IBAction)fajitas1:(id)sender` method   ,

Try this , in your stop button event

```
if([elSonido4 isPlaying])
    {
        NSLog(@"was playing and now paused");
        [elSonido4 pause];
    }
else {NSLog (@"Button tapped but audio is over");}
```

Assuming you've used `<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>` in your .h File.

Comment: whatever you've changed in your code, please paste it by editing your question to track the problem

Comment: Hope you've binded the method with button touch event. tell me do you get the message printed or does go inside the if statement ?

Comment: It doesn't work again man.. - (IBAction)stopPressed:(id)sender{
    if([elSonido4 isPlaying])
    {
        NSLog(@"was playing");
        [elSonido4 pause];
    }
    
} thats what i did

Comment: I clean and built the product again  but no i don't get it in the console the was playing although everything is linked.. i don't get it..

Comment: The console is not printing means, you are tapping the stop button after that the Player has stopped playing. The song is over. Or You haven't propely binded the Stop button. Check by debugging ,does the stop Method get called ?

Comment: It doesn't and i have no idea why.. and yes i have avaudioplayer delagate along with the imported avfoundation.h

Comment: Simple, bind that button again. and check by debugging.

Comment: Again no luck.. I give up. Thanks anw

Comment: Don't give up, try again, I edited my answer. check it again. it must work , I have pasted from my live project code.

Comment: Observe Console , you will understand your mistake

Comment: If nothing is printed ,means you haven't bind the button properly.

Comment: It prints Button tapped but audio is over though which means pause function isn't working

Comment: It means your Audio playing is over. You are tapping after that the playing is over.

Comment: I replaced pause with stop but the same thing happens:  Button tapped but audio is over

Comment: there must be something wrong with elSonido4 variable, otherwise everything is Perfect. I have tried the same code and its running perfectly.

Comment: I don't know probably. anw, thx ill try something again later

Comment: Please edit the relevant information into the question and/or answer, or even post new answers with new details if that is warranted. The comment section of a question/answer is only meant for relevant information regarding the actual post at hand, like mistakes, requests for more details, etc. not for long discussions even though they may be helpful to the people involved. If you need to continue this discussion, consider taking it to a chat room instead.